# Is it accurate to say that pi just provides an approximation of the answer?

Tags: calculus, limits

The *exact* value of pi is not known yet but we have been able to calculate it upto billionth place. Does it imply that formulas using *pi* don't really provide the *perfect* answer but rather a very fine approximation of answer?

Is there something to do with the *limits*? I have read that it makes the answer *perfect*?

*(I'm fairly new to calculus).*

Comment: No, we have exact formulae for $\pi$, it's just we do not have a finite, teriminating sequence of digits.

Comment: We have the exact value of pi.  We just can't represent it in decimal form without approximating it (it's *really* hard to write out *infinitely* many digits, don't ya know).

Comment: @Bye_World wait what!? We have exact value? Can you provide me any source?

Comment: @AdamHughes pi isn't just non-terminating, it is also non-repeating. Implying that its exact value isn't known.

Comment: @Anoneemus There are *tons* of ways of specifying it's exact value.  For instance, it's given by: $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Comment: @Anoneemus Of course it is. It is the only value between $2$ and $4$ for which $\sin x=0$.

Comment: It is known that $\pi$ is an irrational number, hence the digits go on forever without repetition. So you will never be able to write down in decimal form since there are infinitely many digits. When the others are saying that "we have the exact value" they are saying that we have means of achieving $\pi$ to any desired precision.

Comment: @Erf There is more to it than just being able to achieve an arbitrarily precise approximation. There are numbers where we can achieve an arbitrarily precise approximation, but do not even know if the number is rational.

Comment: @Eff Ah, so that means that since we don't have the exact value (since it's irrational), we would also won't be having exact answers. For eg: When pi is used in a formula, it gives an approx answer. Isn't it?

Comment: The exact value of $\pi$ is $4(1- 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + \cdots )$

Comment: @Anoneemus You keep making the assumption that a number can't "have an exact value" if we can't right it out as a decimal or fraction.  But that means that $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an exact number either.  Ludicrous! ;)

Comment: @zhw. Yeah, that's my point, you can't write it down (provided you have all the space you need to write it down). You can only approximate it which means that the formulas using it would just be an approximation? Am I right?

Comment: Do we have an exact value for $1/3$? After all, $1/3 = 3/10 +3/100 + 3/1000 + \cdots$ And it never ends!

Comment: @zhw. Yes, 1/3 has repeating decimal places. So we can satisfactorily say that it is 0.66. However, pi is non-repeating which *probably* makes it approximation?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, true, like the Euler-Mascheroni constant. However, what I mean is that for example
$$\pi = \sqrt{6\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}$$
exactly. But I think OP's confusion comes from the decimal expansion. To calculate the decimal expansion of $\pi$ to any desired precision requires including more terms in the series.

Comment: @Anoneemus Yes $1/3$ has repeating decimal places like any other rational number, which $\pi$ isn't, but what do you mean we satisfactorily can say that it is $0.66$? First off, I think you meant $0.33$, but still I don't understand. The decimal digits never end in $1/3$ either, i.e. $1/3 = 0.333333...$ In fact, $\pi = 3.14159$ is "closer" to true than $1/3 = 0.33.$

Comment: @Eff Oh, I'm sorry for the mistake, I meant 0.33 only. Anyway, I'm convinced with your argument, however, I'm more concerened about *pi* as we are using it more often with our calculations. If its value isn't exactly known *i.e. can't be represented in decimal form*, then it probably implies that the formulas using it are just an approximation? This is my concern, that am I right to assume that formulas using *pi* are just a very close approximation of perfect answer?

Comment: @Anoneemus I said exact formula, not exact value in terms of a decimal representation. The two are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No.

For example,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6 $$
is a precise mathematical statement and not just an approximation. That you run into difficulties when you want to use a specific notation to express $\frac{\pi^2}6$ or do only finitely many calculations to compute the left hand side, that is "your problem", not the problem of the mathematical statement.

However, when physicists use the rule of thumb that
$$ 1\text{ year}\approx \pi\cdot 10^7\text{ s}$$
then this is mnemonically nice, but really just an approximation ...

Comment: "is a precise mathematical statement and not just an approximation". May I know how? What I believe is that, if there's a pi in any formula and if the value of pi is kept in there, then the answer returned will be just an approximation since one of the value (i.e pi) in the formula was an approximation.

Comment: In all my years of physics I've never heard that rule of thumb, very entertaining